# Why use a static function that returns new this() instead of a constructor?

Tags: javascript

While reading some open source code, I came across this (cleaned up) snippet of code below.

```
class Foo  {

    constructor(bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

    static create(bar) {
            return new this(bar);   
    }
}
```

My question is why would someone use a static function that returns new this() instead of a constructor?

Are there any differences between `new Foo(bar)` and `Foo.create(bar)`?

Comment: It depends on the use case. You might want to have factory methods that would be more complex later.

Comment: Other than that, in several circumstances, especially when dealing with reflection (for instance, consider typescript), you can define an interface that forces the implementation of such method, giving a new instance of that item. In that case, invoking a static method of a class is significantly easier (to read and implement) rather than invoking the constructor's `new`.